# Round negative float numbers to floats

Tags: python

I am trying to round some negative floating numbers, the format i want is like the below print/format way, not the round. The problem is that the print approach is not "clean", since it outputs a string with spaces, I got this code from another similar question here in Stackoverflow. The question is how to format/round the numbers like the print below. Thank you

```
theta = 0.33161255787892263
math = 0 + (1-0) * (1-math.cos(theta))**5

round(math,8) # Result: 4.8e-07 # 
print("{:18.8f}".format(math)) # Result: '        0.00000048' #
```

Comment: Why not use `{:0.8f}` or if you want pad with '0' instead of spaces, just use `{:018.8f}`.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. You claim that 'the print approach is not "clean", since it outputs a string with spaces`, but you then ask "how to format/round the numbers like the print below". To get the same results as that print, just do what that print does. If you want different result, why are you asking how to get that result, and what result do you actually want instead?

Comment: abarnet: not sure if i didnt make myself clear. I want the result of the print but in a float number not string.

Comment: Marcin: val = ("{:0.8f}".format(math)), then float(val). The result returns to a negative power floating point number, i want to keep the decimal format as the string. how i do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "I want the result of the print but in a float number not string" and "The result returns to a negative power floating point number, i want to keep the decimal format as the string". But you *can't* do that because you have no control over the internal representation of a `float`: they are *all* stored in a binary form of scientific notation. See the Wikipedia article on [floating-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) for details.

So it doesn't matter whether you do

`v = 0.00000048`

or

`v = 4.8e-07`

both of those statements have an identical effect.

Note that many fractional numbers that terminate when written in decimal may repeat when written in binary. The only fractions that terminate when written in binary are of the form `n / (2 ** b)`, where n and b are integers. Thus even an innocuous-looking number like 0.2 doesn't terminate when converted to binary. (See the Wiki link for a fuller explanation). Because of this issue it's generally **not** a good idea to round floating-point numbers until you've finished all calculations with them.

If you convert a string to float and back again it has to be converted from decimal to binary and back again. So such an operation shouldn't be used in an attempt to "clean up" a number because of the possible rounding errors at each conversion step.

Of course, sometimes you *do* need to apply rounding to a `float` that you are going to continue calculating with, but if so, you should proceed with caution and make sure you really do understand what you're doing to your data.

...

There are a few other strange things with the code you posted.

`math = 0 + (1-0) * (1-math.cos(theta))**5`

Firstly, you should **not** use the name of a module that you've imported as a variable name. After the above statement is executed `math` now refers to the result of the calculation, not the math module, so if you tried to do `x = math.cos(0.5)` you'd get an error. Similarly, don't use `int`, `str`, `list`, etc as variable names.

Secondly, the `0 + (1-0) *` is virtually useless. So the above statement could be re-written as

`result = (1 - math.cos(theta)) ** 5`

And the whole code snippet would become

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import math

theta = 0.33161255787892263
result = (1 - math.cos(theta)) ** 5

print round(result, 8)
print("{0:.8f}".format(result))
```

**output**

```
4.8e-07
0.00000048
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The "math" variable you are right, I realized myself that after some errors. The 0 + (1-0)* is part of the formula, in the case it's useless but then the values change, this is the values of a reflection formula from 0 to 90 degrees. The problem with the result 4.8e-07 is that the host application where i am using python won't read that number, but it will read 0.00000048, so i need to somehow transform the values. when i try to transform it to float again it doesnt work. Is there any way? Thank you

Comment: Ok. But are you sure that formula is correct? That exponent of `5` seems strange. Should it be `.5`? I don't understand the problem you're having with that host application. Why can't you just convert the `float` to a string using either `"{0:.8f}".format(result)` or the older-style `"%.8f" % result` ?

Comment: yeah the exponent is correct, is the brdf curve of a reflection formula, can be 5 or other number, standard is five. I don't want to print the numbers, I need to have them on a variable as a number (0.0000048...)

Comment: I want to convert the string to a float instead, but the float like this: 0.0004... thanks

Comment: Exactly how are you passing this float to your host application?

Comment: Just as a variable within a for loop: refVal = reflt0 + (float(1-reflt0)) * (1-math.cos(theta))**5. When reflt0 is 0 the values are exponential negative, i want them to pass them like this: 0.0004.. instead of the edxponential version which is the same but i need them in decimals. Thanks

Comment: In that case, what I said at the start of my answer applies: "you have no control over the internal representation of a float: they are _all_ stored in a binary form of scientific notation".